# SQLite Database "context" passed to adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) to use SQLite db in my android app.
Since I am a beginner I'm having problems understanding "context" parameter used in the example.

I want to call adapter and insert/update/delete records from a class that does not extend activity which in this example stands for context.

Now I don't know what to pass in the adapter as context, since I'm not calling adapter from activity.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Could you please show some code?

Comment: the code is posted in the example link i used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass the ActivityName.this as class context as argument to the adapter class's constructor
the ActivityName is the name of the Activityclass in which you are calling the adapter

Comment: the problem is that im not calling adapter from activity ... so the only way would be passing the activity all the way to adapter? or could i call context in some static way?

Comment: thanx JayDeep, will accept your anwser so u gain reputation :)

Answer (score 9):

you could imagine that the context defines WHERE/WHEN the sqlite database exists.  sqlite databases do not exist on their own, they exist within the confines of your activity, thus in your activity's context.

for the next steps you must understand that the context is a dynamic "thing" (in reallife you could imagine it as someone's HERE and NOW).  the context is individual to the activity and its moment, just as your here and now are yours and yours only and change over time.

if you are calling a class from within your activity, then this does the trick (passing the activity's context from within the activity itself is OK - sorta like you saying to your buddy: this is how i am feeling NOW).

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Context contextNew = this;
       myClass(contextNew);
```

an easy all around solution (panacea) would be to create a static Context variable (contextVariable) inside MyActivity and access it directly from without via: MyActivity.contextVariable.  but that does not work, because you get an error when you try to declare/use a static Context variable.

So, if you plan on using sqlite inside a service that is NOT called from within the main activity, like, for example, a service triggered by a broadcast receiver (neither a service nor a receiver have a context per se), then you must access the original application's context from within said receiver.

accessing the original activity's context is simple, but far from obvious.

this works for me (thanx @ZiGi and @Cristian):

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;

public class BatchUploadGpsData extends Service {
    public Context contextNew;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        contextNew = getApplicationContext();
```

this is an example from  working code that uploads navigation data to a database on the web every time the android device connects to a WIFI network.  i have a receiver listening to connectivity changes (existing as a separate class called directly "from" Manifest file).

i hope that this makes sense, if you want more detail on this, check out  [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301057/starting-a-service-on-android-platform/11593475#11593475) where i have the complete (barebones) code for said receiver.

Comment: ps: for security reasons, a sqlite db only exists inside your application's sandbox, therefore you MUST first have access to said sandbox, a.k.a. CONTEXT.

Answer (score 2):

As you see in the example, there is a context passed to the ToDoAdapter. You can pass activity as a context or activity.getApplicationContext(). Read about context [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Comment: thanx Vladimir. Its starting to make sense... i will be passing context from my activity class..