# How to create sqlite database at the time of android app installation?

Tags: android

I am having Registration screen as my first screen but before that i want to create database. is it possible to create database at time of installation in android rather than creating in first activity.

Answer (score 14):

This is a great article that helps http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

1. Create the sqlite db using SQLite Database Browser and store it in your assests folder
2. When app launches, copy the db from assets to your apps data directory
3. Open the DB

This way you don't have to parse csv files or dynamically create the db on the device, saving time during first load.

Comment: How to avoid second step and make the copying process to run only once instead on performing each time? We can place a check condition to verify the db presence but is there any other way like creating at the time of installation?

Comment: The Link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a previously created database in your application,at the time of installation the you need to create a database put it in assets folder and then copy it in application.
refer this links:
    [SQLite Database "context" passed to adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879957/android-sqlite-database-context-question/5880048#5880048)

[Database not copying from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945196/database-not-copying-from-assets/5945326#5945326)

[adding your own SQLite database to an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086962/adding-your-own-sqlite-database-to-an-android-application/5948819#5948819)