# accessing sqlite file in android

Tags: android

I have a sqlite file. I want to use it in my application.
Can anyone share proper example as how I can do that.

I was not sure if .sqlite file can be used so I have also made .db file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this..
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Android databases are sqlite files, so you can just use the standard Android database API.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Answer (score 0):

Please check below

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer on this links for sample code:

[SQLite Database "context" passed to adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879957/android-sqlite-database-context-question/5880048#5880048)

[Database not copying from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945196/database-not-copying-from-assets/5945326#5945326)

[adding your own SQLite database to an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086962/adding-your-own-sqlite-database-to-an-android-application/5948819#5948819)